# Material-UI pickers, partial date / multiple formats

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm using the Material-UI-pickers library and have created a KeyboardDatePicker element that I would like to have a dynamic behaviour, allowing the user to enter partial dates by using the keyboard (while the behaviour of the picker popup should remain the same). I want 1998, 1998-04, 1998-04-12 to all be valid inputs.

I've been reading through the documentation but can't figure out a way to make this work. Any ideas?

https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker

https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker